# Using the in keyword in OCAML

Tags: ocaml

I am confused what the keyword `in` does in OCAML. When do i need to use it ?
The only example I came close to understanding is :

```
let quit_loop = ref false in
while not !quit_loop do
  print_string "Have you had enough yet? (y/n) ";
  let str = read_line () in
  if str.[0] = 'y' then
    quit_loop := true
done;;
```

or

```
let x = 10 in
let y = 20 in
x + y ;;
```

what does in indicate here ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The best way to look at it is that `in` is not a separate keyword. Instead, there's an expression that looks like `let v = expr1 in expr2`. This is the way in OCaml to define a "local" variable. What it's saying is that you're going to use `v` as a named value in `expr2`, and its value when it appears in `expr2` is the value of `expr1`.

I suspect the only reason this is confusing at all is that there's a different construct in OCaml for defining "global" variables. At the top level of a module you can say `let v = expr`. This defines a global name that is (in general) exported from the module.

All of the examples you give are of the first kind; that is, they're defining local variables named `quit_loop`, `str`, `x`, and `y`.

As a matter of syntax, `in` is mostly acting like punctuation; it allows a parser for the language to tell where `expr1` stops and `expr2` begins. This is especially necessary in ML languages, where putting two expressions next to each other has a specific (and very commonly used) meaning.

**Update**

By request, here are some examples of `let ... in`:

```
let compare_lengths a b =
    (* Here "let ... in" is used to name values used throughout
     * the computation (i.e., to make local variables).
     *)
    let alen = List.length a in
    let blen = List.length b in
    if alen < blen then -1
    else if alen > blen then 1
    else 0


let rec split list =
    (* Here "let ... in" is used to name
     * the parts of an intermediate result.
     *)
    match list with
    | [] -> ([], [])
    | (a, b) :: rest ->
        let (ra, rb) = split rest in
        (a :: ra, b :: rb)


let euclidean_distance (x1, y1) (x2, y2) =
    (* Here "let ... in" defines a nested helper function.
     *)
    let sqr f = f *. f in
    sqrt (sqr (x2 -. x1) +. sqr (y2 -. y1))
```

Comment: Hi. Can you clarify this with an example? Like fill up expr1 and expr2 with actual expression. Or point me towards a simple piece of code that uses in,

Comment: Any OCaml code that you look at will use `let ... in`. It's an absolutely basic part of the language. But I'll add some examples to my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I started learning OCaml today and this is my first functional language. I imagine everyone who googled this question probably is a newbie too. I appreciate the edit.

Comment: You could also look at the tutorials at OCaml.org: https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/