# OCaml meaning of "in"

Tags: function, functional-programming, ocaml

Lets assume the following function

```
val foo : int -> int -> bool -> int

let foo x y b = 
  let x,y = if x > y then y,x else x,y in
  let rec loop x y b =
    if x >= then x
    else if b then loop (x+1) y (not b)
    else loop x (y-1) (not b)
  in
  loop x y b
```

I still don't quite understand the concept of the "in".
Does the line mean "let x,y = ... in" that it is executed immediately or only when you "Call" it? And when i dont need to call it why do i need the last line loop x y b?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ocaml keyword "in"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72479842/ocaml-keyword-in)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32672704/using-the-in-keyword-in-ocaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in` is just part of the OCaml syntax - `let PATTERN = EXPR1 in EXPR2` is an expression which binds the result of `EXPR1` to `PATTERN` and then evaluates `EXPR2` with the new bindings present. In some languages like F# and Haskell, you don't (always) need `in` - it's inferred from the indentation. OCaml syntax is indentation insensitive which requires it to have an explicit `in`.

> Does the line mean "let x,y = ... in" that it is executed immediately or only when you "Call" it?

It's evaluated immediately.

> And when i dont need to call it why do i need the last line loop x y b?

In this code, the previous line defines a function named `loop` with 3 arguments, and then later you call the function with the arguments `x y b`.

Comment: Ok i kinda get it. But I don't quite understand why the first let is executed immediately and the second not. I guess the first one is kinda like to define a variable in the procedural languages?

Comment: The second one is also immediately executed - it immediately defines a function (named `loop` with 3 arguments `x y b`). You have to call the function in order to execute the code inside, which you do at the end.

Comment: Yes, the first one defines local variables named `x` and `y` and the second one defines a local function named `loop`.

Comment: When do i know if it is a local variable and when it is a function? Sorry if i ask silly question, but i dont understand it completely o_O

Comment: @EraZer Note the difference between `let f = ...` and `let f x = ...`. If there is an argument, then it's a function.

Comment: Ahhh. That's why it didn't work when I did `let x y = if x > y then y x else x y in`. Since I created a function x with the parameter y here, right?

Comment: @EraZer yes, that creates a function named `x` with argument `y`. `let x, y = ` assigns values to two variables, `x` and `y`.

Comment: Perhaps with a comment thread like this, the answer should be amended to answer some of these subsequent questions.